# knockout validation configure is not a function

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I am getting ko.validation.configure is not a function. I have required the plugin just before the statement. How can this be?

```
require('knockout-validation');
ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As an AMD loader, require should be used with this pattern:

```
require(['knockout-validation'],function(koVal){
  koVal.configure({
    insertMessages: false
  });      
});
```

If you want to use your pattern, the module should be stored in a variable, and used via that variable:

```
var koVal = require('knockout-validation');
```

However, in this case, you need to access `ko.validation` functionality through `ko`. So you have to explicitly require the `knockout` dependency, to have it available. To do so, you need to use the first pattern, like this:

```
define(['knockout', 'knockout-validation'], function (ko, validation) {
   // use ko, and ko.validation as usual
};
```

Please, get sure that your config allows `require` to find both `knockout` and `knockout-validation`.